# Ошибки Maven 3 в IntelliJ IDEA 14?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Есть отдельно установленный Maven 3.3.3 (в настройках IntelliJ IDEA 14 указан именно он).

[image: ошибка Maven плагинов]

[image: В настройках среды репозиторий с ошибкой]

В чем могут быть причины ошибки?
Может, установить какой-нибудь альтернативный репозиторий для Maven 3 (в IDEA по умолчанию Maven2)?

Мавен3 установлен на этом же компьютере

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Idea выбрана папка установки

[image: настройка Maven в IDE]

Comment: 3 мавен удалено установлен?

Comment: попробуйте URL заменить на http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

Comment: замена URL на repo1.maven.org/maven2 не помогла